# Difference between Active data position & Active presentation position

Tags: c, console, escaping, cursor-position, ansi-escape

What is the key output difference between Active data position and Active presentation position defined separately in ECMA-48 in 4.2.5 and 4.2.6 ?

I tried to move my cursor to a different coordinate in the console with Escape Sequences defined in ECMA-48.

And I encountered two implementations doing the same thing but actually telling something different in the definitions.

According to the definitions:

> ### CUP
>
> CUP causes the active presentation position to be moved in the presentation component ...
>
> ### HVP
>
> HVP causes the active data position to be moved in the data component ...

When tested with C code:

CUP:

```
printf("Hello");
printf("\x1b" "[" "%d" ";" "%d" "H", 5, 5);
printf("World");
```

HVP:

```
printf("Hello");
printf("\x1b" "[" "%d" ";" "%d" "f", 5, 5);
printf("World");
```

They produce the same results.

So, whats the difference that the standard is trying to make by defining these two terms?

> EDIT :
>
> According to 6.1.5,
>
> In a uni-directional device, whether it has a presentation component only or a presentation component
>   and a data component, there is no difference between the active data position and the active presentation
>   position.
>
> And in page 16 (6.1.5), in the first paragrpah:
>
> Because of the possible differences between character
>   progression and character path, as in some bi-directional environments, the coordinates of the active data
>   position in the data component and of the active presentation position in the presentation component
>   may differ.
>
> ***Explain Active Presentation Position and Active Data Position in a Bi-directional Environments with Practical Example.***

And, which one should I use to move around the console?

> [N.B: Don't mention to use ncurses in your recommendation. But any recommendation on Implementation of ECMA-48 is welcomed]

Comment: From what I remember from the old days (>30 years ago) I used  `"\x1b" "[" "%d" ";" "%d" "H"` for positionning the cursor. BTW: I'd rather write this like this `printf("\x1b[%d;%dH", 5, 5);`

Comment: @Jabberwocky what kind of shell you used back then?

Comment: No shell, but directly outputting escape sequences from pascal programs on a VT100 terminal connected to an antiquated minicomputer (Norsk Data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says: for a *uni-directional* device there is no difference.  You'd have to investigate a *bi-directional* device (and have the corresponding modes enabled).

It's referring to a device where the cursor could be made to *advance* after the terminal printed a character in some other way than *left-to-right*, wrapping *top-to-bottom*.  You can see something like this in a GUI web browser visiting a page that's in Arabic: text goes from right-to-left, but you can have text components embedded in it which are written from left-to-right.  The data- and presentation positions are used to keep that mixture straight.  (If there's no mixture, it's a trivial problem, but accordingly of little interest).

VT100s never did that.  The last of DEC's terminals in the early/mid-1990s, the VT520 did not (it's likely that no **widely** used terminal supported bi-directional controls).  Although there was an **`HVP`** in [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) [2nd edition](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-48,%204th%20Edition,%20December%201986.pdf) (August 1979), the wording about direction was added in the 4th edition (December 1986).  It was revised somewhat for the [5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf) (June 1991).

A few terminal emulators can do this, but lacking a hardware terminal (which would have demonstrated the features which the members of the committee who wrote the documents had in mind), there are differences and disagreements over the interpretation.

Comment: Can you tell whether the modern linux terminals or terminal emulators like bash, zsh, cmd, powershell are bi-directional or not?

Comment: It's not a matter of "modern" (a commonly-misused term).  BIDI in konsole and mlterm is much older than this forum.  The programs you mention are not terminal emulators, nor are they "modern".

Comment: My bad, do these shells or command line interpreters or any of linux consoles are bi-directional or not? (I am actually trying to say the command line *things* that we normally regularly use)

Comment: konsole and mlterm run on Linux (and more, since they're moderately portable).